# Batch File Do action when find duplicate id in a log file, & in next run do action when find new duplicate id not the previous one

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd

I am working in a Organization where An application create log file daily, and contains Batch_Id in form of incremented 7 digit format(Ex. Batch_Id = 1234567, Batch_Id = 1234568). We have to monitor string Batch_Id in current day log file if same Batch_Id comes more than one times then there is problem and send mail else OK.
I have got bellow code that is working fine

```
     @echo off
echo Working !!!
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type test.log ^| findstr "Queue_ID"') do (
   set $Line=%%a
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=^=," %%b in ('echo !$Line!') do (
      set $Value=%%b
      set $Value=#Queue_id!$Value: =!
      if not defined !$Value! (set !$Value!=1) else (set $liste=!$Liste!,[!$Value!]) 
))

if defined $Liste (
  echo Error List : !$Liste!
  echo sending Mail...
  S:\blat.exe -body !$Liste! -subject "KSD Error" -tf %recipients% -server %smtpserver% -f %sender%)
endlocal
echo Done !!!
Pause
```

This script when finish, send mail if found same Queue_ID multiple times. I have to run this script in every hour so I needed if in previous log scan it has send mail for some Queue_ID then in next log scan, it will not send mail for that previous Queue_ID means if found new Queue_ID multiple times then only send mail

I am very new to Batch Script and I am not able to implement this but I have some Idea may be help !!

In every time log scan we can write multiple Queue_ID in a text file and during next scan we search also for text file's Queue_ID and ignore them if found . Log file created daily with current date(Ex. 20140821.LOG) . so we have to overwrite this text file when next day first time script will run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generates a daily "duplicates" files to test against when reading the main log file. Each time a duplicated is found, the line is stored in the duplicates log.

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "logFile=20140804.log"

    set "previous=%logFile%.prev"
    for %%a in ("%previous%") do for %%b in ("%%~dpa\*.log.prev") do if /i not "%%~nxa"=="%%~nxb" del "%%~fb"
    if not exist "%previous%" >"%previous%" echo(@

    set "dup="
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==," %%b in (
        'findstr /l /c:"Queue_ID = " "%logFile%" ^| findstr /v /l /g:"%previous%"'
    ) do for %%a in (%%b) do if not defined "%%a" ( set ""%%a"=1" ) else if !"%%a"! equ 1 (
            set ""%%a"=2"
            >>"%previous%" echo(Queue_ID = %%a
            set "dup=!dup! [%%a]"
        )
    )

    set "recipients= .... "
    set "smtpserver= .... "
    set "sender= .... "
    if defined dup (
        rem "S:\blat.exe" -body "%dup%" -subject "KSD Error" -tf "%recipients%" -server "%smtpserver%" -f "%sender%"
        for %%b in (%dup%) do for /f "delims=[]" %%a in ("%%b") do call printLoop.bat %%a
    )
```

Inside the `for` command, the first `findstr` command will search the log file for the lines to be processed. The second `findstr` filters this list: only those lines not found in the *"previous"* log are retrieved (to avoid errors in the filter process, previous code ensures the *previous* list is not empty).

Then, the `for` command tokenizes the line. The equal sign and the comma are used as delimiters. This leaves the ID as the second token in the line. This ID is used as a variable name. For each readed line, it test if a variable with this name has been defined. If it has not beed defined, this is the first time the ID is readed, and the variable is defined with a value of 1. If the variable was defined, it is a duplicate. If the value of the variable is 1 (first duplicate for this value), the ID is written in the *previous* log, the ID concatenated to a list that will be later used to do send the mail and the value in the variable changed to 2 to avoid writting/appeding the same ID if it is found again in the input log.

**edited** to adapt to comments:

- added removal of non needed ".prev" files
- changed code to remove spaces in queue_id numbers so the next step is easier to code
- added call to batch file to process duplicates, with the code of the duplicate as argument.

Comment: your script is working very fine even better from my previous script performance wise.
Here is real log file [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByEtsyft3LhENGFXNDFzckxKZ1U/edit) please check once, there is two Queue_ID field in log file
 please verify script will work fine in all condition because I will deploy this script directly in Production   and Please do me one more favour please add mail part also which send mail in finding newly duplicate Queue_ID mail code is "S:\blat.exe -body this is body -subject "KSD Error" -tf %recipients% -server %smtpserver% -f %sender%)"

Comment: @user3856852, code updated. By knowing the real log file format the code is now a little more simple, only one `for` command. Prior to production deploy test against a set of log files. Maybe there is some format changes not present in the linked log. Sorry, i can not test the mail send part.

Comment: Worked, Thanks a lot!
you are champ :)

Comment: would you please do a little bit more effort by adding some comment so I can make understand this code to my colleague also !

Comment: Thanks, Its created "%logFile%.prev" file for every day, would you please make some changes that script delete previous date "%logFile%.prev" file, means only contain current date  "%logFile%.prev" file, it will save space and remove unnecessary file handling

Comment: @user3856852, included code to delete previous `.prev` files

Comment: could you help me again! These Queue_ID need to submit to a batch file name printLoop.bat for fixing issue which accept Queue_ID as parameter.
please embed this in above code so code run this printLoop.bat batch file for every duplicate Queue_ID.
And it would be better code send mail first for getting Duplicate queue_id and then after one more mail, fixing those by running printLoop.bat batch file

Comment: When i wrote this line in a new batch file "call printloop.bat 7750755" for example I got bellow snippet in cmd window

`C:\Scripts\PrintLoop>call KSDPrintloop.bat 7750755

C:\Scripts\PrintLoop>Sqlplus -S /NOLOG @c:\Scripts\PrintLoop\Login.txt
Enter value for print_queue_id:`

Not able to pass Queue_ID to the last line for processing fix.
Please help, if you need all code snippet let me know

Comment: @user3856852, sorry but you have a sqlplus script inside `login.txt` asking you the ID. You have to change the script, not the batch.

Comment: can we do in this way first run the fix script then when it asks for Queue_ID `Enter value for print_queue_id:` then only provide Queue_ID !!!!! or Is there any alternative to make it possible

Comment: @user3856852, if something like `echo %queueId% | sqlplus ....` works, change the batch file. If not, you can generate the sql script from the batch file, or you can modify the sql script to accept the data from the command line instead of prompt for it.